# Open street map json to data.frame in R

Tags: json, r, list, openstreetmap

I have a *JSON* file with open street map POI-s.

An original element from the json looks like:

```
"type": "way",
"id": 4899669,
"nodes": [
 31929852,
 31929903,
 31929921,
 31929869,
 31929861,
 31929852
],
"tags": {
"amenity": "parking"}
```

I used this script to import *JSON* to *R*:

```
library(jsonlite)
as <- fromJSON(file.choose())
as_bp<-as$elements
as_bp_way<-subset(as_bp,type=="way")
```

I got a data.frame but my problem is that the nodes class is *list* .

I'd like to convert it in such format :

```
type    id  tags$amenity    nodes
way 4899669 parking 31929852
way 4899669 parking 31929903
way 4899669 parking 31929921
way 4899669 parking 31929869
way 4899669 parking 31929861
way 4899669 parking 31929852
```

One of the problem could be the different number of tags.

Comment: What do you want to do if there's more than one tag in a record? What are you going to do with it when you get it in a data frame anyway? It might not be the best structure.

Comment: I want to get every single tags in a single column. i have another JSON ,wich contains only node types from OpenStreetMap data. Every node POI has an id , so i could join it with the nodes attribute from my "way" JSON data.